# probability of / that

Tags: word-usage

> 1. The probability that you can get a high score in this exam is high.
> 2. The high probability that you can get a high score in this exam is for sure.
> 3. The probability of you getting a high score in this exam is high.
> 4. The high probability of you getting a high score in this exam is for sure.

All of these sentence patterns are natural to use?

Comment: sentences 2 and 4 don't seem natural. It doesn't make sense to use probability with "for sure".

Comment: then how about "obvious"?

Comment: Even in case of "obvious", it doesn't sound natural. Obvious also suggests a kind of certainty. You can either say something like "It is obvious that he'll get a high score" or "it is highly possible that he'll get a high score". Both sentences have different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

None of those sound very natural, unfortunately.  Here are some alternatives:

> It's quite likely you'll receive high marks on this exam.
>
> I think you will score very high on this exam.
>
> You'll probably do quite well on this exam.

or even

> I'm sure you'll pass this exam with flying colors!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a homework question, but.... Number 1 is fine, if a little stilted. Number 2 makes next to no sense to me. The high probability is for sure? What does it mean for a probability to be "for sure." Number 3 seems fine as as well, but certain sticklers might argue for a possessive: "your getting" as opposed to "you getting." Most English speakers agree that this is awkward. Number 4: Same problem as number as number 2. At a guess, I would say that number 1 is the "correct" answers, but no one would blink at number 3. Most people would say "good score" rather than "high score," though, especially since "high" is used later in the sentence.